# How can we send data from android phone over 4G and wifi simultanesly

Tags: android, networking

I want to send data from Android phone over 4G(cellular network) and WIFI at the same time. I know we can send data either over 4G or WIFI at a time. But i want to send data over both networks.Performance is not an issue, I want to send data from both adopter to single IP address and port

Comment: Can you explain more, since at a time you can only send data over 4G or WIFI. But to send over both means? When you will call API at that time whatever network is available your request goes through that then how can you use another network simultaneously. This case is only possible if your connected network goes off and your phone now switched to some other network.

Comment: I don't want to either switch the network or select another network, I want to use both Internet adapters so i can increase data rate by using two network at a time... and thanks @NikhilLotke

Comment: I got your point. I think that is not possible to send data over both networks since kernel decides at runtime if you are connected to 4G and you also connected to WIFI in that case Kernel prefers WIFI connection.

Comment: "_I want to use both Internet adapters so i can increase data rate by using two network at a time._" It doesn't actually work that way. Using two separate connection like that can actually cause _slower_ performance because you will get out-of-order packet delivery. TCP can handle that, but it will cost you in performance. It will actually kill real-time protocols because they cannot handle out-of-order packets.

Comment: @RonMaupin,  For me performance is not an issue, Please tell me is their any way to do so.

Comment: Performance seems to be the issue. You want to use both networks to increase the data rate, but you can slow the data rate by using two different networks. You will also kill real-time protocols by doing that because they cannot handle out-of-order delivery. TCP can, but it will cause resends, etc. that can slow your throughput. This will not achieve what you are asking.

Comment: I simply want to use both adopter(Android phone network adopter) at same time, I can understand what you are trying to explain me. But dear my simple task to use both adopter at same time. At this stage i dont care about throughput, and thanks @RonMaupin